# .NET Serialization and weekcalendar - Undefined events.events

Tags: jquery, vb.net, json, calendar

I have been trying to implement the [jQuery weekcalendar](https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/wiki) using .net. What I can't seem to figure out is why weekcalendar states events.events is undefined after I make an ajax call to a webmethod I created which returns JSON.

Below is the relevant code:

Javascript:

```
function getEventData() {
    var dataSource = $('#ddlAdvisors').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{ AdvisorID: '" + $('#ddlAdvisors').val() + "'}",
        url: "<page>.aspx/<webmethod>",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(data.d);

            // Fixes datetime

            $.each(jsonObj.events, function (key, value) {
                value.start = eval(value.start.slice(1, -1))
                value.end = eval(value.end.slice(1, -1))
            });

        return jsonObj;
        }
    });
}
```

JSON directly from the webmethod (Also, if you're looking at that Date, before you comment read the above javascript that fixes it)

```
d = { "events" : [{
        "id":68263,
        "start":"\/Date(1262619000000)\/",
        "end":"\/Date(1262622600000)\/",
        "comment":"..comment..",
        "title":"First Name Last Name"
    }]
}
```

WebMethod

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function <name>(ByVal AdvisorID As String) As String

    Dim lookup As New <namespace>.<class>
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = lookup.<function>(Convert.ToInt16(AdvisorID))

    Dim serializer As System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()

    Dim events As New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Generic.Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Object))))
    Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
    Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
        Next
        rows.Add(row)
    Next

    member.Add("events", rows)
    events.Add("events", member)

    Return serializer.Serialize(member)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The `success` member in your `$.ajax` call is an anonymous function. It is executed as a callback of the asynchronous request and does not return `jsonObj` to the caller of `getEventData().` What you need to do instead is either call a function to make use of `jsonObj` or process the object there, i.e.:

```
success: function (data) {

    ...

    ProcessEventData(jsonObj);

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought about that - added the async member which was the main reason the events object was undefined.